# Shifted symmteric function and Gromov witten invariants

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, mathematical-physics

I am having some conceptual misunderstanding with the calculation of stationary Gromov written invariants as in the paper
https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v163-n2-p05.pdf
by eq 3.1
My problem arises in the case when $k_i$ is equal to or greater than 2 in the expression
$$\langle\mu\mid \tau_{k_i}(w) \mid \nu \rangle $$
Say using eq 3.1 we get
$$\langle 1\mid \tau_{2}(w) \mid 1 \rangle = p_{3}([1])/3! $$
where $p_k$ is shifted symmetric function as in eq 0.14 in that paper.
The case when $\mu=[d]$ I suppose the connected and disconnected Gromov written invariants are same?
Calculation reveals that
$p_3 (1)= 247/960$
but I can see for connected Gromow written invariants computed by eq 3.25 it is
$$\langle 1\mid \tau_{2}(w) \mid 1 \rangle = 1/24$$
So what is the mistake of me calculating the $p_3(1)$?
Also eq 0.18 in the paper define
$p_3 (\lambda)=k![z^k]e(\lambda, z)$ where $e(\lambda,z)= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\exp(\lambda_i -i+\frac12)$
Calculating from this does not give $p_3 (1)$ to be finite.